# How do you use a linq to sql join two tables and return the result?

Tags: linq-to-sql, model-view-controller, join, ienumerable, anonymous-types

I have been looking on Stack overflow but none of the answers seem to fully sort out this problem. The error I'm getting is:

Cannot initialize type 'mvcTest.Models.MakeModelSpec' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

I have created a new type like this to get over the anonymous type error

```
public class MakeModelSpec 
{
    public int MakeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 

public IQueryable<MakeModelSpec> GetSpecs(int makeid)
        {

            var searchspec = from spec in db.Specs
                             join model in db.Models on spec.ModelID equals model.ModelID
                             join make in db.Makes on model.MakeID equals make.MakeId
                             select new MakeModelSpec
                             {
                                 make.MakeId,
                                 spec.Name,
                             };

        if (makeid != -1)
        {
            searchspec = searchspec.Where(make => make.MakeId == makeid);
        }
        return searchspec;
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful I'm using MVC c# and a sql server db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing your `MakeModelSpec` "with a collection initializer".

Collections such as `List<Item>` can be initialized as such

```
new List<Item>
{
    Item1,
    Item2
}
```

Your code is interpreted as trying to do that, as it does not supply the parameters, which are required for *object initialization*

```
new MakeModelSpec
{
   Make = make.MakeId,
   Name = spec.Name
}
```

Note that you *can* do object initialization without specifying parameter names if you're using anonymous types.

```
new
{
   make.MakeId,
   spec.Name
}
```

The only reason the above isn't interpreted as a collection initializer is that the type is anonymous, so that you're making up property names as you go. Therefore, the property names you're used to create the object can be *inferred*.

Hence, in the following example, `Name =` is redundant, because that property would be called `Name` anyway, but `Id =` is *not* redundant, because that causes the anonymous type to have a property called `Id` rather than `MakeId` which it would infer if you were not supplying a name:

```
new
{
   Id = make.MakeId,
   Name = spec.Name
}
```

If `MakeModelSpec` were to implement `IEnumerable`, so that it was actually a collection of something, then you would be able to do

```
new MakeModelSpec
{
    MakeModelSpec1,
    MakeModelSpec2
}
```

... provided that `MakeModelSpec1` and `-2` are of a type that `MakeModelSpec#Add` accepts. This is what the compiler thinks you are trying to do.

Comment: Cheers Mate that totally sorted me out